# Delete AWS Amplify Function - Resource cannot be removed because it has a dependency on another resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-amplify

I have added an S3 lambda trigger in my AWS Amplify project. However when I try to remove that lambda trigger using `amplify remove function`, it shows the following error.

```
Resource cannot be removed because it has a dependency on another resource
Dependency: S3 - s3xxxxxxxx
An error occurred when removing the resources from the local directory
```

[image: AWS Amplify remove function error]

[AWS Amplify Documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/function/build-options/) does not have a clear guide to remove lambda functions. So, **how can I remove the function without removing the S3 resource?**

Answer (score 6):

1. Since I created a trigger on the S3 resource, I need to remove that trigger first by running `amplify update storage`. Then choose the options that you configured previously. When Amplify CLI prompts to select an option, choose `Remove the Trigger`.

[image: Running amplify update storage in CLI]

2. Then run `amplify push` to sync local changes with the cloud.
3. Now, if we run `amplify remove function` again, and choose the S3 trigger function. It will execute without an error. Just remember to do another `amplify push` to sync and remove the function at last.